# In knockout js, how to iterate through arrays of objects dynamically?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, knockout.js, google-workspace

*I've searched through SO before asking but I didn't find anything that fit.*

I'm trying to use App Scripts in Google Workspace to create a list of users.

I'm getting the users successfully from Google.

That array is being passed to JS successfully.

I must not understand something about KO because I'm seeing this.users being updated successfully in the console log. But the view is never updated. The

does empty itself when `this.users = []`. But when I do `this.users = u` or if I for loop and try `this.users.push(u[i])`, it does not updated.

So the main question is: Why doesn't the list updated with `this.users =u;` ?
Thanks!

Code.GS:

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page')
      .evaluate();
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

function getUsers() {
    var users = [];
  var options = {
    domain: 'mydomain.com', // anonymized for this.
    projection: 'full',
    viewType: 'admin_view',
    maxResults: 100,
    orderBy: 'email', 
  };
  
  do { 
    var response = AdminDirectory.Users.list(options);
    response.users.forEach(function (user) {
      const u = {id:user.id,
      fullName:user.name.fullName,
      primaryEmail:user.primaryEmail,
      org:user.orgUnitPath,
      lastLogin:user.lastLoginTime,
      enrolled2fa:user.isEnrolledIn2Sv}
      users.push(u);
    });

    if (response.nextPageToken) {
      options.pageToken = response.nextPageToken;
    }
  } while (response.nextPageToken);
  Logger.log(users); // just for testing.
  return users
}
```

Page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>User Manager</h1>
    <div>
      <ul id="usersUL" data-bind="foreach: users">
        <li data-bind="text: primaryEmail">Loading...</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- KnockoutjS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <?!= include('Javascript'); ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Javascript.html *(Google requires the .html... This is the right way for app script... Also, I realize the applyBindings is in the OnLoad. I get the same results when it's not.)*

```
<script>
  var vm = {
  users: ko.observableArray(),
  updateUsers: function(u) {
    var self = this;
    self.users([{primaryEmail:"Loading"}]);
    console.log(this.users);
    /*
  for (let i = 0; i < u.length; i++) {
    this.users.push(u[i]);
  }
  */
  this.users = u;
    console.log(this.users);
  }
}
function UsersViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  users: ko.observableArray();
}

window.onload = function() {
  console.log("applying bindings");
  ko.applyBindings(vm, document.querySelector("#app"));
  console.log("getting users");
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(vm.updateUsers).getUsers();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Using the assignment operator `=` does not trigger any of the observable's subscribers. Can you try changing `this.users = u;` to `this.users(u);` to see if that changes anything?

Comment: @nbokmans That worked! Sort of.  this.users(u); resulted in "this.users is not a function"... self.users resulted in the same error. vm.users(u) worked! I wonder why this and self wouldn't work?

Comment: When you `this.users = u;` you are rescoping the variable from observableArray to a JavaScript array. That's my guess. It's a pretty common mistake in Knockout. Try this

`self.Users: ko.observableArraay([]);
....
....
ko.mapping.fromJS(u, {}, self.Users);`

I changed the case of self.users to self.Users for clarity